# .NET Framework 4.0 - Smallest installer?

Tags: .net, installation

I have to install the .NET Framework 4.0 to run a program, and I've googled around to find what to install, but the only thing I can find is [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7).

The description there says (emphasis mine);

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4
>   redistributable package installs the
>   .NET Framework runtime and associated
>   files that are required to run **and
>   develop** applications to target the
>   .NET Framework 4.

Now I know that for Java, there are two packages you can install - the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) which only allows you to run Java programs, not develop them, and the Java Development Kit (JDK) which allows you to develop them as well. The JDK is much bigger than the JRE, and it's not necessary if you just want to run a Java program.

So I'm wondering, is the situation for C# similar? I don't want to download something that allows me to run *and develop* .NET applications if I can avoid it. I would much rather download something smaller that only allows me to run them. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this page out:

*SmallestDotNet.com is a single page site that does one thing. It tells you the smallest, easiest download you'd need to get the .NET Framework on your system.*

http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/

Answer (score 2):

Try the [client profile](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17113)

Depending on what dependencies your app has, you may still need the full profile though.  Best way is to try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to .NET 4 there are 4 options:

1. x86 Client Profile 29 MB.
2. x86 Full Framework 35 MB.
3. x86 and x64 Client Profile 41 MB.
4. x86 and x64 Full Framework 48 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Search for a redistributable.I think that on the MS site you can find only the redist package,not the VS and SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is actually a subset of the .NET framework which can run applications in and out-of-browser.  Given the small install footprint you may wish to consider this as a valid option should it meet your requirements.